# exec-path and $PATH

Tags: path, exec-path

I have seen examples online where people add paths to the default path in Emacs with:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin/")
```

I am new to Elisp, and I think I understand what the statement above does, but I have a few questions:

- In **what order** does Emacs search through the execution paths? For example, does it consider the value of `$PATH` (env. variable) at all (and if so, before or after `exec-path`?)
- How can I **prepend** multiple such paths? Can I just keep concatenating them? e.g.

  ```
  (add-to-list 'exec-path "PATH1", "PATH2")
  ```

  or should I do:

  ```
  (add-to-list 'exec-path "PATH1:PATH2:PATH3")
  ```

I also found this interesting package on GitHub: [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell). Why is there a need for a package for this?

> **Motivation**
>
> Ever find that a command works in your shell, but not in Emacs?
>
> This happens a lot on OS X, where an Emacs instance started from the
>   GUI inherits a default set of environment variables.
>
> This library works solves this problem by copying important
>   environment variables from the user's shell: it works by asking your
>   shell to print out the variables of interest, then copying them into
>   the Emacs environment.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs and Elisp! I'm still pretty fresh with the topic myself and don't know the answers to your questions, but I thought I'd mention something that has made life a heck of a lot easier: the describe functions. e.g. `(describe-function 'add-to-list)` (`C-h f`) will give you the doc for the `add-to-list` function, as well as links to the source. There's also `(describe-variable 'exec-path)` (`C-h v`). This isn't meant to be a RTFM comment -- these docs don't answer all the questions you listed, just something useful.

Comment: Thanks @jtmoulia! I will definitely keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: In addition to `C-h v exec-path`, use the manual(s) (Emacs and Elisp). In a manual, `i exec-path` directs you to a helpful explanation. *Ask Emacs first* - you won't be sorry you did.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## 1) `PATH` and `exec-path`

Emacs does set `exec-path` from the value of `PATH` on startup, but will not look at it again later. But if you run a command, it will inherit `PATH`, not `exec-path`, so subprocesses can find different commands than Emacs does.

As Francesco says, this can be especially confusing for `shell-command`, as that does not run a process directly, but calls a shell to run it, which will use `PATH`, not `exec-path`.

## 2) Adding multiple paths to `exec-path`

Just call `add-to-list` repeatedly:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "PATH1")
(add-to-list 'exec-path "PATH2")
```

Do note that `add-to-list` adds to the beginning of the list, so this will end up with `"PATH2"` being in the `exec-path` before `"PATH1"`.

You can also use more "low-level" access to lists:

```
(setq exec-path (append '("PATH1" "PATH2")
                        exec-path))
```

This will add `"PATH1"` and `"PATH2"` to your `exec-path`, in that order.

## 3) Mac OS' PATH

The problem on Mac OS X is that Mac OS does not set the environment the same when you call a program from the global UI or when you call it from a shell. This means that running Emacs from a shell will result in different environment variables being set than when you run it from the finder. This is especially annoying if you set environment variables in `.bashrc` or similar, as that won't affect the "global" Emacs.

The package apparently starts a shell and imports environment variables from there, mimicing the environment you get from a shell in a globally-started Emacs.

Comment: Thanks Jorgen. Regarding Q3: Do you happen to know where the default `PATH` is defined for programs started from the global UI (desktop environment)?  I am having the same problem with `PYTHONPATH` in `elpy` :). When I start Emacs from the desktop, Emacs is not aware of my `PYTHONPATH` definitions in my `.zshenv` file (an init file for `zsh`), which is very frustrating, since `elpy` does not know then where to find my Python packages. I am happy to move these `PYTHONPATH` definitions to a different shell `init` file (although ideally I would like Emacs to use the definitions from my `.zshenv`)

Comment: I am afraid I do not know much at all about Mac OS X. A quick google got me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x which seems to indicate that launchd.conf is the right place. If all you need this for is Emacs, you can of course just set both `exec-path` and `PATH` in your `.emacs`. You can set `PATH` using `(setenv "PATH" (format "%s:%s" "/new/path/element" (getenv "PATH")))`.

Comment: Thanks. I know the following Q diverges a bit from the OP, but is there any way to specify in Emacs the `PYTHONPATH` that `elpy` should use?

Comment: You can modify `process-environment`, for example using `setenv`. You can do that in `elpy-mode-hook`, but it is a globsl variable and making it buffer-local can easily lead to confusing behavior.

Answer (score 9):

When emacs starts a new external process using primitive functions such as `call-process` or `start-process`, the executable is searched in `exec-path` (and not `$PATH`)

However, a function such as `shell-command` starts the shell as a subprocess and passes it the command you want to run. In order to execute this command, the shell will then try to find the executable in `$PATH` (and not in `exec-path`).

Therefore, `exec-path` is what counts most for external processes which are started by emacs itself, whereas `$PATH` is what counts for commands you run yourself with higher-level function (using <kbd>M-!</kbd> for example)

---

If you want to add multiple directories to `exec-path`, you should use
`add-to-list` multiple times.

You can do it either manually

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "dir1")
(add-to-list 'exec-path "dir2")
```

or using a loop

```
(dolist (dir '("dir1" "dir2"))
  (add-to-list 'exec-path dir))
```

---

Regarding your third question, if emacs was launched from the desktop environment, it inherits the environment from it, which might be less complete than that of a full shell.

This means that it might sometimes be necessary to complete Emacs' value for `$PATH` using what a regular shell sees. This is the purpose of the `exec-path-from-shell` library you mention.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following solution on Mac 12.4. It works.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath

```lisp
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  "Set up Emacs' `exec-path' and PATH environment variable to match
that used by the user's shell.

This is particularly useful under Mac OS X and macOS, where GUI
apps are not started from a shell."
  (interactive)
  (let ((path-from-shell (replace-regexp-in-string
              "[ \t\n]*$" "" (shell-command-to-string
                      "$SHELL --login -c 'echo $PATH'"
                            ))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

(set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH)
```

Comment: You can remove the `replace-regexp-in-string` call by running echo with the `-n` option (which won't print a new line, so you won't have to remove that).