# Find in Project with Ack

Tags: projectile

Trying to find in Project with Projectile.. In the Projectile menu i have

- Find in project (grep)
- Find in project (ack)

Grep works but if i try ack i get..

```
-*- mode: ack-and-a-half; default-directory: "~/Desktop/proj/" -*- Ack started at Mon Dec 29
16:39:24
 --ignore-dir=.idea --ignore-dir=.eunit --ignore-dir=.git --ignore-dir=.hg --ignore-dir=.fslckout --ignore-dir=.bzr --ignore-dir=_darcs --ignore-dir=.tox --ignore-dir=.svn --ignore-dir=build --ignore-file=is:TAGS --nocolor --nogroup --column --smart-case --env -- audio zsh:1: command not found: --ignore-dir=.idea
Ack exited abnormally with code 127 at Mon Dec 29 16:39:24
```

I haven't done much to get it to work except install `ack-and-a-half` and `ag.el` from MELPA (I'm confused about which I want / how to replace one with the other) but don't know how to proceed or debug - I can't find any documentation

ack and ag both work from the terminal and my homebrew dir has been added to the emacs path

any help for an emacs begginer is much appreciated

Comment: I would reckon that the variable that `ack-and-a-half` uses to store the program name is `nil`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ack-and-a-half is now abandonware](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/584).
I don't think plain `projectile-ack` is still functional in current Projectile -- maybe you should try `ag`.
If you really want `ack`, you could give `helm-projectile-ack` a try.

Comment: Thanks very much for the heads up. I'm a bit scared of Helm - feels too soon to jump in, but maybe ill give it a try

Comment: @mustISignUp Helm is good, and I very much recommend `ag` (or `pt` if you often work with multi-byte-encoded in your files).  If you want a good config for `helm-ag`, I recommend L389 of [my own `.emacs`](https://github.com/vermiculus/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el#L389)

Comment: Helm is not difficult at all. You can start easy with [my guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html).

Answer (score 5):

According to [the source](https://github.com/rferraz/ack-and-a-half/blob/master/ack-and-a-half.el#L338), I would reckon `ack-and-a-half-executable` is `nil`.  This would explain the output you get.  Again from [the source](https://github.com/rferraz/ack-and-a-half/blob/master/ack-and-a-half.el#L72), it would appear that `ack` is not visible to Emacs.

Note the TODO:

```lisp
; TODO Determine how to fall back to using ack-grep if ack is not found.
(defcustom ack-and-a-half-executable (executable-find "ack")
  "*The location of the ack executable"
  :group 'ack-and-a-half
  :type 'file)

;...

(compilation-start
  (mapconcat 'identity
             (nconc (list ack-and-a-half-executable)
                    arguments)
             " ")
  'ack-and-a-half-mode))
```

See [exec-path and $PATH](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/550/2264) for information on how to show Emacs where `ack` is.

Note that @TuDo's answer stands as good advice -- drop `ack-and-a-half` in favor of another solution (such as `helm-ag` or simply `ag.el`) -- but I hope this answer actually diagnosis the problem for you or anyone else who has become dependent on `ack-and-a-half`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. Im still learning how to approach problems in Emacs and this helps alot.

Comment: @mustISignUp Some just comes from experience (i.e. messing up often enough to learn what to look for), but Emacs' help system is truly great.  I recommend exploring `M-x apropos` (or even better if you have an idea of what you're looking for: `M-x helm-apropos`) -- this is how I found that variable :)

Answer (score 0):

- The `ack` utility is better than the `grep` utility – but `apt-get install ack` installs a japanese kanji package!
- Do this instead: Use `pkg-divert` to force the package name to `ack`:

  ```
  dpkg-divert --local --divert /usr/bin/ack --rename --add /usr/bin/ack-grep
  apt-get install ; apt-get install ack-grep -f -y --force-yes
  ```
- For more see: http://betterthangrep.com
- Suggest installing the Perl App::Ack package too.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You should take a look at the 'about' page to learn more about the format here. For instance, signatures are unnecessary since they're automatically added.  Also note that this doesn't really fully answer the question – you should explain why this may work.