# Associate Emacs with 7zip for .odt export?

Tags: odt

After asking [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/zip-program-for-odt-export), I have downloaded [7zip for Windows](http://www.7-zip.org/).

When I try to export to .odt, I am still getting this: "OpenDocument export failed: Executable "zip" needed for creating OpenDocument files."

What is my next step?

Comment: this might apply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625306/org-mode-zip-needed-how-to-over-come

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625306/org-mode-zip-needed-how-to-over-come Here is how to add 7zip to path: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/550/exec-path-and-path

Answer (score 1):

After you have associated 7zip with files that have a give extension (e.g. `.zip`), in the usual way for MS Windows (I don't think that's your question), you can have Emacs open such files using that associated program.

To do that, start with the Emacs Wiki [Category W32](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWThirtyTwo). There you will find, among other things:

- [MS Shell Execute](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsShellExecute) - tell Emacs to use Windows programs associated with given file types
- [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) - open files from Dired using the associated Windows programs
- [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#WindowsFileAssociations) - use Windows file associations as bookmark actions

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late for an answer but here it goes anyway. If you search `ox-odt.el` you can see that the error message you're getting comes from `org-odt--export-wrap` which is the macro called by `org-odt-export-to-odf` and `org-odt-export-to-odt` to create the actual `ODT` file. Inside `ox-odt--export-wrap` there is this little piece of code:

```
(unless (executable-find "zip")
     ;; Not at all OSes ship with zip by default
     (error "Executable \"zip\" needed for creating OpenDocument files"))
```

that will prevent the process to continue unless the `zip` excecutable exists in your `PATH`. Also a few lines below there's this:

```
(cmds `(("zip" "-mX0" ,target-name "mimetype")
          ("zip" "-rmTq" ,target-name ".")))
```

which defines how to call the `zip` command in order to create an `ODT` file. Considering all of the above you have at least three options here:

1. Modify the `ox-odt.el` file so it uses the `7z` command instead of `zip`.
2. Wrap your calls to `7z` into some kind of `zip.cmd` command.
3. Download `zip` for Windows, in fact you should get [GNU on Windows](http://wiki.github.com/bmatzelle/gow/) or [Cygwin](http://wiki.github.com/bmatzelle/gow/), any of them will save you a lot of troubles while working with Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need export `org` to `odt`, see [org-mode zip needed, how to over come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625306/org-mode-zip-needed-how-to-over-come/52034701#52034701).

If you need 7-Zip as your zip program, you need download [7-Zip Extra: standalone console version](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and put 7-zip extra in Windows `%PATH%`.

Call `(make-zip-bat (executable-find "7za"))` to generate `zip.bat` and put it in your `%PATH%` and `exec-path`.

`zip.bat` for `7za` looks like:

```
@echo off
REM zip.bat for 7za on Windows
REM generated by More Reasonable Emacs https://github.com/junjiemars/.emacs.d

REM local variable declaration

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set _OPT=%*
set _ZIP=
set _ARGV=

REM parsing command line arguments

:getopt
if "%1"=="-mX0" set _OPT=%_OPT:-mX0=-mx0% & shift & goto :getopt
if "%1"=="-0" set _OPT=%_OPT:-0=-mx0% & shift & goto :getopt
if "%1"=="-9" set _OPT=%_OPT:-9=-mx9% & shift & goto :getopt

REM ignore options
if "%1"=="-r" set _OPT=%_OPT:-r=% & shift & goto :getopt
if "%1"=="--filesync" set _OPT=%_OPT:--filesync=% & shift & goto :getopt
if "%1"=="-rmTq" set _OPT=%_OPT:-rmTq=% & shift & goto :getopt

REM extract zip and argv
if not "%1"=="" (
  if "%_ZIP%"=="" (
    if "%_ARGV%"=="" (
      set _ZIP=%1
    )
  ) else (
    set _ARGV=%_ARGV% %1
  )
  set _OPT=!_OPT:%1=!
  shift
  goto :getopt
)

REM 7za call
7za a %_OPT% -tzip -- %_ZIP% %_ARGV%
if exist %_ZIP% (
  7za d %_OPT% -tzip -- %_ZIP% %_ZIP%
)
```

Now, export `org` to `odt` should works, see more [More Reasonable Emacs: zip program](https://github.com/junjiemars/.emacs.d/#zip-program)

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to export to .odt, I am still getting this: "OpenDocument export failed: Executable "zip" needed for creating OpenDocument files."

Based on https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-04/msg00489.html, you can use the zip package from following links

```
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm
```

---

Based on https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-04/msg00538.html, you may also use the `zip` executable from

https://fossies.org/windows/misc/zip300xn.zip/