# How get python major version without any additional package?

Tags: python

I need a function that return major version of "current" python interpreter. Possible choices are 2 or 3. How can I get it? Please, help me with this func.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`shell-command-to-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html) and [`split-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html):

```
(second (split-string (shell-command-to-string "python --version")))
==> "2.7.12+"
```

If you insist on a major version *number*, you can use [`string-to-number`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/String-Conversion.html):

```
(string-to-number (first (split-string (second (split-string (shell-command-to-string "python --version"))) "\\.")))
==> 2
```

or (see [`string-match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html) and [`match-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html))

```
(let ((pv (shell-command-to-string "python --version")))
  (if (string-match "Python \\([0-9]+\\)\\." pv)
      (string-to-number (match-string 1 pv))
      (error "Unexpected `python --version` output [%s]" pv)))
==> 2
```

Note that in all cases you will get the version of whatever `python` executable found in the [`exec-path`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/550/795).
IOW, *normally* this would be the system-wide `/usr/bin/python`, unless you started Emacs in a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) or set it [inside Emacs](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el).

Comment: This would report only the systems default, not the version at place inside a virtualenv maybe.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler: not necessarily, please see note and the end.

Comment: There might exist links from python to python2 or 3. While inside Emacs source, by shebang or other customization, the default might be not selected.