# cannot find binary even though it's in my exec-path

Tags: path, exec-path

when I do `C-h v` and look up `exec-path`, I get the following:

```
("/usr/local/bin"
 "/usr/bin"
 "/bin"
 "/usr/local/games"
 "/usr/games"
 "/usr/lib/emacs/27.1/x86_64-linux-gnu"
 "/usr/local/cuda/bin")
```

However, when I try to run `nvcc` from `M-x compile`, it says "nvcc not found". If I give it the full path `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc`, it works fine.

I thought having the path in `exec-path` is supposed to let me use `nvcc`, why is it not? Also, when I do `M-! echo "$PATH"`, it prints

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

which is missing the last **two** elements of `exec-path` from above. Though I guess that's because `exec-path` takes precedence, so whatever. But in that case, why isn't the last element of `exec-path`  "taking effect" in my case?

Note that when I go into an ordinary terminal (outside emacs) and do `echo "$PATH"`, I get the following:

```
/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

though it's less surprising that emacs didn't capture that path which was from `.bashrc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exec-path and $PATH](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/550/exec-path-and-path)

Comment: no, because that answer tells me to do the thing I've already tried and doesn't work: put the item in `exec-path`, while I need to set the `PATH` env variable to actually get it to work

Comment: The first paragragh of the accepted answer does say "But if you run a command, it will inherit PATH, not exec-path, so subprocesses can find different commands than Emacs does." and comments on the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in order to get `nvcc` to work from `M-x compile`.

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/cuda/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))
```

I actually also reverted the changes to `exec-path`, as those didn't seem to matter one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The function 'compile' runs the command you give it in a shell.

The command is found by the shell through function `start-file-process-shell-command` and so the environment variable $PATH is the one that is used. Thus explaining whey your [solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71916/9874) of adding "/usr/local/cuda/bin:" to PATH is needed.

See this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/553/9874) for more